# What's the best current proof of the Poincaré conjecture?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, math-history, geometric-topology

Is there a current "gold standard" proof of the Poincaré Conjecture? I am interested in reading through the full proof, and some day perhaps reading Perelman's proof/notes. For now, though, I was wondering what the most "polished" version is, which would represent any advances during the 17 years since his publications and the 14 years since the formalization by various groups. I can see that Terry Tao has published some notes recently, but I don't believe he has published a full proof.

Comment: Same as 10-14 years ago.

Comment: So there have been no new publications?

Comment: You might want to post this question to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net), which is more research-oriented than Math.SE.

Comment: There were many advances (and publications) but none simplifies the existing proofs.

Comment: MathOverflow might be a good idea. I believe Moishe but it would be nice to get some additional references

Comment: @gturer sure, go ahead and post it there. But I looked at your profile and I think you are far from ready from reading "the full proof."

Comment: This question was kind of [already asked](https://mathoverflow.net/a/37599/1446) on MO; the roadmap mentioned there really hasn't changed.  Of course it's missing all the references for 3-manifold theory, but it's already quite substantial list of reading.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks, I had somehow missed this question when I looked earlier. However, this is also a pretty old question. I'm rather surprised to hear that nothing new has come out. I'm going to leave the question to see if anyone is aware of anything new.

Answer (score 2):

Still, the only (essentially) self-contained treatment of Perelman's proof of the Poincare Conjecture is

*Morgan, John; Tian, Gang*, Ricci flow and the Poincaré conjecture, Clay Mathematics Monographs 3. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS); Cambridge, MA: Clay Mathematics Institute (ISBN 978-0-8218-4328-4/hbk). xlii, 521 p. (2007). [ZBL1179.57045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1179.57045).

The only major part of the proof which they only sketch but do not provide details of is the short-time existence theorem for RF. One thing they do not address is the equivalence  between the topological and smooth category for 3-dimensional manifolds, but, as long as one is only interested in classifying smooth manifolds up to diffeomorphism, this does not matter.

Since then, there were numerous advances in understanding Ricci Flow in dimension 3 as well as in higher dimensions, but these did not lead to a substantial simplification of the proof. Needless to say, I do not recommend reading either the above book or other accounts of the proof of the 3-dimensional Poincare Conjecture (and, more generally, the Geometrization Conjecture) to an undergraduate student. My suggestion instead would be to read a textbook on Differential (Riemannian) Geometry.

Comment: I appreciate the pedagogical advice and you are right in the traditional sense but I don't think this should be part of your response as it isn't germane to the question itself.

In my case, the reason I want such a reference is as a long-term goal: I intend to struggle with the proof for several years not just to learn the proof but to serve as a sort of roadmap towards interesting material, to study back from. Peter Schloze has discussed the benefit of a similar approach earlier in his career.

Comment: I think you should be careful when advising a younger student not to look into something which interests them: this can at times be beneficial so that we don't get discouraged by failing to do something which is too hard, but if it is too hard, we'll probably figure that out pretty quickly on our own.

Comment: @gturer: I think, we will just agree to disagree on this. In any case, you can of course ignore my advice. My advice to any student interested in a specialized subject S is to start by reading background material in the general area  A of math that includes S  (Riemannian Geometry in this particular case). Then, depending on the degree of difficulty of S and how comfortable the student got with A, either proceed with S, or, in some cases, look for a PhD program with an advisor well-versed in S.

Comment: Richard Bamler did not need my advice, but he wrote this UG diploma thesis on RF (his UG advisor knew the work of Perelman, Kleiner and Lott extremely well) and then went to Princeton to work Tian and wrote a PhD thesis on RF. Bamler is now one of the best experts in the world on this subject.

Comment: I do think that this is good advice, and I hope I did not offend. 

Many of us won't be Richard Balmers or Peter Schlozes, and I think what you have said is good to keep us grounded and focused. But I also think that a field with such a propensity for discouragement and burnout and such a high attrition rate can only survive on the dreams--even improbable--of those that wish to pursue it. Certainly this has been necessary for me, and thankfully I have found mentors to encourage this, but it is so often at odds with the structures of undergraduate pedagogy that it bears emphasis.

Comment: Also, how would you compare this treatment to that of Cao and Zhu? I've been looking at their monograph and it seems well-written and complete; is there something that Morgan and Tian do better?